# Как реализовать баннеры как в Google play?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Как реализовать подобные баннеры на странице? Можете скинуть ссылку на хорошую статью, чтобы тут не расписывать!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это всё можно реализовать через RecyclerView.
https://habrahabr.ru/post/308872/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/237101/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Если б сделал ответом, принял бы твой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам список таких баннеров реализуется с помощью RecyclerView
А элементы списка с помощью CardView

[Статья посвященная RecyclerView на англ](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)